# How to make a website Browser friendly?

Tags: html, css, browser, web

I Know this is common question in  web Development but what what should be things that i must take care while developing a HTML website? Why does my site look different on different browsers, till now i checked it on Chrome and Firefox. So dimensions on both were too different. Is there any specific code for CROSS BROWSER compatibility ?

Comment: There are many ways to make sure a website is cross-browser friendly, too many to list in a single answer. Either list the specific issues you are having and we can help with them or use Google to find tutorials/articles/videos/courses on how to make sure sites are cross-browser friendly

Comment: You can use this to make it look and feel good: [link](http://getbootstrap.com/) and you can use angular js also to make the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would develop for one browser and worry about cross browser compatibility later. Most of the differences are between WebKit browsers (chrome, Safari, opera), internet explorer browsers (8,9,10,11), and Firefox. I would recommend developing on one browser, and then checking your site in others afterwards. I doubt you will have too many things to fix. Mostly there will just be styles that may not work the same way on certain browsers. One thing to keep in mind is that your site will probably never be perfect in every browser. For the websites I design, I have a list of browsers I support. There are things that just won't work on ie6 and not enough people use it to make the effort worthwhile. A good rule is to worry about the latest version of each browser or the latest few versions. As you can see, there's no simple answer, just make sure to check your work.